# Custom spark filter function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a custom filter function that does some custom comparison which would be complicate if its not in a function

```
  def myCustomFilter(a: DataFrame, b: DataFrame, aCol: String, bCol: String)
(implicit spark: SparkSession): Boolean = {
    if (a(aCol).isNull) {

       // Some custom comparison
       return true or false
    }
    // Some custom comparison
    return true or false
   }
```

And use it like

```
a
.join(b, a(myColA1) === b(myColB1), "inner")
.filter(myCustomFilter(a, b, myColA2, myColB2))
```

But this doesn't work because filter takes a column and not boolean?

What is the canonical way to create custom filter function in spark?

Comment: `lit(true)` creates a column containing the literal value `true`. This may help. That being said, what's the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your entire Row object to your custom filter and use the columns accordingly

**As I'm unaware of your data samples I have used employee & department examples to answer your question, hope that is helpful in solving ur issue**

```
employeeDF.show()

+-----+------+---------+----+----------+----+----+------+                       
|empno| ename|      job| mgr|  hiredate| sal|comm|deptno|
+-----+------+---------+----+----------+----+----+------+
| 7369| SMITH|    CLERK|7902|1980-12-17| 800|null|    20|
| 7499| ALLEN| SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-20|1600| 300|    30|
| 7521|  WARD| SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-22|1250| 500|    30|
| 7566| JONES|  MANAGER|7839|1981-04-02|2975|null|    20|
| 7654|MARTIN| SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-28|1250|1400|    30|
| 7698| BLAKE|  MANAGER|7839|1981-05-01|2850|null|    30|
| 7782| CLARK|  MANAGER|7839|1981-06-09|2450|null|    10|
| 7788| SCOTT|  ANALYST|7566|1982-12-09|3000|null|    20|
| 7839|  KING|PRESIDENT|null|1981-11-17|5000|null|    10|
| 7844|TURNER| SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-08|1500|   0|    30|
| 7876| ADAMS|    CLERK|7788|1983-01-12|1100|null|    20|
| 7900| JAMES|    CLERK|7698|1981-12-03| 950|null|    30|
| 7902|  FORD|  ANALYST|7566|1981-12-03|3000|null|    20|
| 7934|MILLER|    CLERK|7782|1982-01-23|1300|null|    10|
+-----+------+---------+----+----------+----+----+------+

departmentDF.show()

+------+----------+--------+
|deptno|     dname|location|
+------+----------+--------+
|    10|ACCOUNTING|NEW YORK|
|    20|  RESEARCH|  DALLAS|
|    30|     SALES| CHICAGO|
|    40|OPERATIONS|  BOSTON|
+------+----------+--------+
```

The filter condition that I have defined is to get all the deptno == 30 and comm > 0, so the filter function looks like below

```
def customFilter(row: Row): Boolean = {
  val deptno = row.getAs[Int]("deptno")
  val comm = row.getAs[Int]("comm")
  deptno == 30 && comm > 0
}
```

The result when I apply join and filter conditions

```
employeeDF.join(departmentDF, Seq("deptno"), "inner").filter(customFilter(_)).show()

+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
|deptno|empno| ename|     job| mgr|  hiredate| sal|comm|dname|location|
+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
|    30| 7499| ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-20|1600| 300|SALES| CHICAGO|
|    30| 7521|  WARD|SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-22|1250| 500|SALES| CHICAGO|
|    30| 7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-28|1250|1400|SALES| CHICAGO|
+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
```

Another way can be

```
employeeDF.join(departmentDF, Seq("deptno"), "inner").filter("deptno = 30 and comm > 0").show()
+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
|deptno|empno| ename|     job| mgr|  hiredate| sal|comm|dname|location|
+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
|    30| 7499| ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-20|1600| 300|SALES| CHICAGO|
|    30| 7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|1981-09-28|1250|1400|SALES| CHICAGO|
|    30| 7521|  WARD|SALESMAN|7698|1981-02-22|1250| 500|SALES| CHICAGO|
+------+-----+------+--------+----+----------+----+----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: This is quite unrelated to OP's question. You changed most of the requirements of OP.

Comment: im just trying to show how the custom filter function needs to be defined & used with some example, as there is no much inputs in the question

Answer (score 0):

The Spark filter method expects a col/lit expression, not a boolean value. To create a custom filter function, you can use the expr method from Spark's SQL functions to build a column expression based on your custom logic.

Here's an example of how you can modify your custom filter function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr

def my_custom_filter(a, b, a_col, b_col):
    condition = col(a_col).isNull() | (col(a_col) > col(b_col))
    return expr(f"({condition._jc})")

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CustomFilterExample").getOrCreate()

# Example DataFrames
data_a = [("Alice", 1, 10), ("Bob", 2, 20), ("Charlie", None, 30)]
data_b = [("Alice", 1, 15), ("Bob", 2, 20), ("David", 3, 30)]

columns = ["name", "id", "value"]

df_a = spark.createDataFrame(data_a, columns)
df_b = spark.createDataFrame(data_b, columns).withColumnRenamed("value", "value_b")

# Usage with aliases
result = df_a.alias("a").join(df_b.alias("b"), col("a.id") == col("b.id"), "inner").filter(my_custom_filter("a", "b", "a.value", "b.value_b"))

result.show()
```

[image: pyspark custom filter]

Make sure to adjust the custom comparison logic inside the my_custom_filter function according to your requirements.